# php файл не корректно отображает кириллицу

Tags: php, кириллица

По нажатию на кнопку, выводиться `$status` и в нём сообщение на русском языке, а в браузере отображает

```
{"response":"\u042d\u0442\u0430 \u044d\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0442\u0440\u043e\u043d\u043d\u0430\u044f \u043f\u043e\u0447\u0442\u0430 \u0443\u0436\u0435 \u0437\u0430\u043d\u044f\u0442\u0430"}
```

Я понимаю что у этой проблемы скорее всего простое решение. Подскажите пожалуйста.

php файл

```
<?php

require "init.php";

$name = $_GET["name"];
$surname = $_GET["surname"];
$patronymic = $_GET["patronymic"];
$email = $_GET["email"];
$phone = $_GET["phone"];
$password = $_GET["password"];


$sql = "select * from registered_users where email = '$email'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
$status = "Эта электронная почта уже занята";
}
else
{
$sql = "insert into registered_users(name,surname,patronymic,email,phone,password) values('$name','$surname','$patronymic','$email','$phone','$password');";
    
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        $status = "ok";
    }
    else
    {
        $status = "error";
    }
}
echo json_encode(array("response"=>$status));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Документацию нужно читать... `echo json_encode(array("response"=> $status), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`
А ещё почитайте про подготавливаемые запросы для безопасности Вашей базы данных. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Спасибо)и извиняюсь, начал изучать php и html позавчера.